# Zoom settings other than 50% 75% 100%,

Tags: front-end

Is it possible to choose a zoom setting other than what's provided at the bottom of each Notebook window (50%, 75%, 100%, 125%, 150%, 200%, 300%)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, "Magnification" -> 1.23]
```

or

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], Magnification -> 1.23]
```